# Java Diagonal Matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I have been wondering how to diagonally wrap, from bottom left, a String into a matrix.
For example:

```
String str = "123456789";

//Output matrix:
//  479
//  258
//  136

//Or if str = "123456789123456";

//Output would be:

//  2
//  73
//  484
//  2595
//  13616
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
     int index = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
     {
         for(int k = matrix.length - 1; k > -1; k--)
         {  
             if(index == word.length())
                 break;
             matrix[k][i] = "" + str.charAt(index);
             index++;
         }
     }
```

Comment: can you explain , how you have written that output matrix ,i am not getting how you want to get output matrix based on your input string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reasonably efficient implementation which I believe is relatively easy to understand.

This code loops over successive diagonals, and when the current position is inside the matrix, it assigns the next character from the string.

In the below chart, the question mark positions are on the diagonal but they're not inside the matrix. No character is taken from the input string for these question mark positions.

```
Diagonal  Matrix
   4      ?
   3      ??
   2      479
   1      258?
   0      136??
```

The loop goes through rows in ascending order, but the assignment to each row is done in reverse because your matrix is upside down when viewed from the normal Java way of indexing arrays: `matrix[size - row - 1]` instead of `matrix[row]`.

There is no need for special treatment of below, at and above the diagonal this way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "123456789";
    int size = 3;

    int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int diagonal = 0; diagonal < size * 2 - 1; diagonal++) {
            int row = diagonal;
            int column = 0;
            while (row >= 0) {
                if (row < size && column < size) {
                    matrix[size - row - 1][column] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(index++));
                }
                row--;
                column++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It also works for larger sized matrices (4x4, 5x5 etc.) but you can only encode values up to 9 in your string - if you want higher values, it's better to encode them in a comma-separated string and split the string into an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not making any claims about efficiency here, but it should work so long as your string fits into a square matrix:

```
static char[][] toDiag(String s)
{
    int sideLen = (int) Math.sqrt(s.length()); // assume string fits into
                                                // square matrix
    char[][] m = new char[sideLen][sideLen];
    int index = 0;
    //fill lower-left section of array
    for (int i = m[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= m[0].length-1-i; k++)
        {
            m[i+k][k] = s.charAt(index++);
        }
    }
    //fill upper-right section of array
    for (int i = sideLen%2==1?sideLen/2:sideLen/2 -1; i <= m[0].length; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= m[0].length-1-i; k++)
        {
            m[k][i+k] = s.charAt(index++);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inString = "123456789";
    int N = (int) Math.sqrt((double) inString.length());
    int out[][] = new int[N][N];
    int index=0;

    //fills elements below the diagonal
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            out[N-1-i+j][j] = Character.getNumericValue(inString.charAt(index++));

    //fills the diagonal
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        out[i][i] = Character.getNumericValue(inString.charAt(index++));

    //fills elements above the diagonal
    for(int i=N-2;i>=0;i--)
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            out[j][N-1-i+j] = Character.getNumericValue(inString.charAt(index++));

    //prints the output
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(out[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```